# read from text file line by line in c programming

Tags: c

How can I read from text file line by line, so each line will be input in the next part of the code, then this part will compare the first line in that file if it is not correct, then it will try the next one and so on, until the correct word is found?

Please can you kindly help?

```
>  FILE *userfp;    // usernames file pointer
      int countusr = 0;  // conter for file lines
      char  word[BUFSIZE];
      char *cpyword;
      userfp = fopen(UsrsFile,"r");

      // check if file exits

      if (userfp == NULL)
       {
        errorMessage("usernames File doesn't exit!");
       }  
 int x = 0; int s=0;
        while (!feof(userfp)) {
                fgets(word, BUFSIZE, userfp);
                if (word[BUFSIZE] == '\n')
                        continue;
                for (s = 0; s < strlen(word); s++)
                        if (word[s] == '\n')
                                //word[s] = ',';
               //cpyword[x] = malloc(BUFSIZE);
                //strcpy(cpyword[x], word);
                //x++;
                printf("%s",word);

        }
```

Comment: There are errors if this is all of your code.  Anyway - where does Usrfile get declared and where does it get a value?  A more usual way to do this is make a copy of each line and destructively parse the line copy with strtok(), then user strcmp() on each word.  Also where does the variable word get declared and the value set?

Comment: Many problems.  Step 1 Suggest `while (fgets(word, sizeof word, userfp) != NULL) {`   2) `if (word[BUFSIZE] == '\n')` --> `if (word[BUFSIZE-2] == '\n')`

Comment: thanks jim , can you give example of how to make each line and destructively parse the line using strtok() and strcamp? the filename is in the main function will be prompted and the name is passed to this function, BUFSIZE is buffer of [4000]

Comment: chux, i have done these changes , but the displayed only the last char in first three line